# Non-smooth curve and taper

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I would like to make a bent cylinder with varying radius. *Taper* and *Bevel* seem like a good way to do this, however, I would prefer that the *Taper* curve is not a spline but a polyline, so that I can make sharp edges.

Ideally I would like it to be a profile function R(t).

EDIT: Below is an example of what I'm not really interested in. It should be a lot more... edgy...

[image]

Comment: Looks like @lemon's, to me... the quick way to get a polyline curve is to convert  a mesh to a curve.. so perhaps you could use a bit of my answer, too. (The  slower way to make a polyline curve is, in Edit mode of  a curve, with a spline selected, right-click menu > _Set Spline Type_.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *"screw modifier"* instead of a taper object.

[image]

The first shape above is the selected edges with a screw on it.

Then it is curved (second and third objects below it).

Depending on what you want:

- The second also has a bevel and subdivision to keep sharp edges but follow the curve smoothly.
- The third only has a curve.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is great. But how did you make the polyline? I can only make splines, when I choose Add->Curve->BezierCurve

Comment: The "pseudo taper" is not a curve, but a mesh with edges only

Comment: Though, you can screw a curve too. (and bevel/subdisivion modifier)

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2D Polyline Taper curve, modifying the radius of Bezier curves:

[image]

Maybe The sharpness of your result is limited by the U resolution of the bevelled and tapered curve? That's set in the *Data* tab, *Shape* panel

As for the maths function, you could use  *Add > Mesh > Math Function > Z Surface*, and set a function in one of X or Y (instead of both),  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> duplicate out one of the mesh's profile edges, <kbd>P</kbd> separate it into a new object, rotate into the right orientation ( as illustrated ) to be a taper curve in Edit mode, and convert the mesh-edge to a curve.

I'm sure, in the past,  I had to enable the shipped add-on *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* to get the math functions, but I don't think you have to, any more.

Comment: Hi Robin... yes. Have seen it and so deleted the comment.

Comment: @lemon all in all, I still think your way would be less of a pain, with a Curve modifier to do the bending..